# How to fill External Item picker using jquery?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, external-list

Set value of a SharePoint 2013 BDC External Item Picker field using JQuery
I want to fill customer name using jquery.  How can fill this when page load?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by getting the ID of the this field via JavaScript and set its default value as the following :

- Open you page > add script editor.
- Add the following code with your control id and its default value

**[Code]**

```
<script>

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setbcs");
function setbcs() {
     var s = document.getElementById(ID of your control);
     s.value = "new value";
}

</script>
```

You can also check alternative methods at

- [Prefill a list form field – External Data](https://spandps.com/2010/10/11/prefill-a-list-form-field-external-data/)
- [Set value of a SharePoint 2010 BDC External Item Picker field using JQuery](https://dilrukj.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/set-value-of-external-item-picker-sharepoint-2010-bdc/)